# How can I write IIS Rewrite multiple subdomains to multiple local port rule?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, subdomain

I want to set reverse proxy rules in IIS for list below.

```
app1.application.com > localhost:26000
app2.application.com > localhost:26001
app3.application.com > localhost:26002
```

I added bindings in single IIS site then defined single rule for port 26000. All of them redirect to app on port 27000.

Here is the rule I added;

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:26000/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

How can I add other rules?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Like this.  Note the 4th rule how I'm doing a temporary redirect to an internet URL.  That's an easy way for "testing" your scripts as its a little more foolproof to do Redirect and internal rewrites.  Typically I get everything working with Redirects (again, use Temporary) and then switch it over to the internal Rewrites.

Finally, you might consider adding a catch-all rewrite after your 3 to redirect either to an error page or to a "default" app.  Since these rules are processed in order (and Stop Processing is set) you can just add that rule without the HTTP_HOST condition at the end.

```
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:26000/{R:1}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(app1\.application\.com)$" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:26001/{R:1}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(app2\.application\.com)$" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule3" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:26002/{R:1}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(app3\.application\.com)$" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule4" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.google.com" redirectType="Temporary" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(app4\.application\.com)$" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
```